# getting the class path or name space of a class in python even if it is nested

Tags: python, serialization, introspection

I'm currently writing a serialization module in Python that can serialize user defined classes. in order to do this I need to get the full name space of the object and write it to a file. I can then use that string to recreate the object.

for example assume that we have the following class structure in a file named `A.py`

```
class B:
    class C:
        pass
```

now with the assumption that `my_klass_string` is the string `"A::B::C"`

```
klasses = my_klass_string.split("::")
if globals().has_key(klasses[0]):   
    klass = globals()[klasses[0]]
else:
    raise TypeError, "No class defined: %s} " % klasses[0]
if len(klasses) > 1:
    for klass_string in klasses:
        if klass.__dict__.has_key(klass_string):
            klass = klass.__dict__[klass_string]
        else:
            raise TypeError, "No class defined: %s} " % klass_string            
klass_obj = klass.__new__(klass)
```

I can create an instance of the class C even though it lies under class `B` in the module `A`.
the above code is equivalent to calling `eval(klass_obj = A.B.C.__new__(A.B.C))`

note:
I'm using `__new__()` here because I'm reconstituting a serialized object and I don't want to init the object as I don't know what parameters the class's `__init__` methods takes. I want to create the object with out calling **init** and then assign attributes to it later.

any way I can create an object of class `A.B.C` from a string. bout how do I go the other way? how to I get a string that describes the full path to the class from an instance of that class even if the class is nested?

Comment: +1 for an interesting and well explained question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot get the "full path to the class given an instance of the
class", for the reason that there is no such thing in Python.  For
instance, building on your example:

```
>>> class B(object):
...     class C(object):
...             pass
... 
>>> D = B.C
>>> x = D()
>>> isinstance(x, B.C)
True
```

What should the "class path" of `x` be?  `D` or `B.C`?  Both are
equally valid, and thus Python does not give you any means of telling one
from the other.

Indeed, even Python's `pickle` module has troubles pickling the object `x`:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> t = open('/tmp/x.pickle', 'w+b')
>>> pickle.dump(x, t)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 1362, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
   (obj, module, name))
  pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.C'>: it's not found as __main__.C
```

So, in general, I see no other option than adding an attribute
to all your classes (say, `_class_path`), and your serialization code would look it up for
recording the class name into the serialized format:

```
class A(object):
  _class_path = 'mymodule.A'
  class B(object):
    _class_path = 'mymodule.A.B'
    ...
```

You can even do this automatically with [some metaclass magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639162/python-determine-if-a-class-is-nested/639588#639588) (but also read the other comments in [the same SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639162/python-determine-if-a-class-is-nested/) for caveats that may apply if you do the `D=B.C` above).

That said, if you can limit your serialization code to (1) instances
of new-style classes, and (2) these classes are defined at the
top-level of a module, then you can just copy what `pickle` does
(function `save_global` at lines 730--768 in pickle.py from Python
2.6).

The idea is that every new-style class defines attributes `__name__`
and `__module__`, which are strings that expand to the class name (as
found in the sources) and the module name (as found in
`sys.modules`); by saving these you can later import the module and
get an instance of the class:

```
__import__(module_name)
class_obj = getattr(sys.modules[module_name], class_name)
```

Comment: +1: excellent highlighting of border case likely to cause many headaches.

Comment: I believe this best answers my question, I know just how stupid what I'm trying to do is but it is still the easiest way to achieve my goal. if I went with a serializer that like JSON or XML I would have to write a complex translator to take the JSON data and build the objects in the ruby side before marshaling them this way I can do a strait load already have th object and them dump them again. the Metaclass magic link help a lot ans it basically describes the only way to determine the path to a nested class.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, in any reasonable non-crazy way. I guess you could find the class name and the module, and then for each class name verify that it exist in the module, and if not, go through all classes that does exist in the module in a hierarchical way until you find it.

But since there is no reason to ever have class hierarchy like that, it's a non-problem. :-)

Also, I know you don't want to hear this at this point in your work, but:

Cross-platform serialization is an interesting subject, but doing it with objects like this is unlikely to be very useful, as the target system must have the exact same object hierarchy installed. You must therefore have two systems written in two different languages that are *exactly* equivalent. That's almost impossible and likely to not be worth the trouble.

You would for example not be able to use any object from Pythons standard library, as those don't exist in Ruby. The end result is that you must make your own object hierarchy that in the end use only basic types like strings and numbers. And in that case, your objects have just become containment for basic primitives, ***and then you can just as well serialize everything with JSON or XML anyway.***

Comment: If I had to option of defining both ends of the system then I wouldn't be doing this. but alas I have to bridge a gap between a poorly designed engine and an editor. and this system DOSE have class hierarchies like that. in fact I think part of it goes 4 levels deep.  so your answer is to go from the `__module__` name and then work my way down looping until I find the right class building the tree along the way?  that sounds like it could work. feels like a hack though. do you know any looping tricks or type testing tricks that could help limit the amount if iterations?

Comment: But to do what you are trying to do now you *do* have to be able to define both ends of the system. If you can't, then you can NOT serialize objects like this.

So, question: WHY are you serializing objects, instead of just serializing data?

Comment: because those object hold data. I have a system that reads data from ruby Marshal files and has data contained in what are basically structs in modify that data in those file I need to be able to read ruby marshal. I tried to write a reader for the format in python with some help from a friend of min and I almost seceded. but some obscure bug prevented me from reading the files reliably some of the files worked and some didn't failing for weird reasons. so I decided to write a ruby program that could actually read and write the format correctly and use it as a translator.

Comment: as I said I have the ruby side working I can go between the correct format for the system I'm trying to bridge and my format. now I just need to be able to write in the correct format on the python end. now what what I can tell I can use the `__module__` attribute of the object to get the module and then loop through the module's `__dict__` attribute testing for class objects. and loop through those objects until I find the path I need.  right? I can;t see a reason that this would fail it's just ugly and slower than I would like.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question of why you are serializing objects. You can on one side export the data into some sort of sane format, like JSON or XML, and then read that in on the other side. That is much simpler, and much more likely to actually work. In this case, if any object you have does not have a representation on the other side, it will fail. If you have a datetime object on the Python side  you *must* on the Ruby side have a module called "datetime" with a class called "datetime" that has the exact same attributes as Pythons datetime.datetime, or it will not work. Do you have this?

Comment: yes I have that, that data I need to serialize has an almost exact replace in both python and ruby. I'm also restricting the objects that can be serialized to basic types of list(arrays in ruby), dictionaries (hashes in ruby), true, false, none, stings, numbers, and then I'm allowing user defined classes that carry only that data. and the only classes I plan to serialize have representations of both sides.

Comment: @Ryex: So since you are restricting the data that can be serialized to basic types Why are you not using an ordinary sane serializing format, such as JSON or XML? Third time I ask that now. Sorry to say this, but I believe you are barking up the wrong path, and you should cut your losses and start over. Use JSON, it's perfect for this and dead easy to use from Python and likely from Ruby as well. Python has support for, in stdlib for 2.6 and 2.7 I think, and there surely are Ruby modules as well.

Comment: i want to second the notion that serializing arbitrary functional objects is generally a bad idea. when i still did things like that my applications were riddled with import problems when trying to unpickle things, and i had to concern myself with lots of tricky questions---a lot of problems that simply go away if you confine yourself to basic JSON data types.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently writing a serialization module in Python that can serialize user defined classes.

**Don't**. The standard library already includes one. Depending on how you count, actually, it includes at least two (`pickle` and `shelve`).

Comment: yes thank you this is very good to know, especially sense it doesn't help. I'm well aware of pythons internal serialization modules but I choose to write my one because I need it to work across languages. I've been successful in ruby and am now working on python. if perhaps you can answer my question please edit your answer, that would be awesome. thanks your time.

Comment: I know we've been insisting on this, but there **already are** well known cross-host, cross-language formats for serialization with freely available (or even built-in to the standard library) writers/parsers. They are called XML, JSON, etc. Can you at least provide a simple explanation of why they do not suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** ways of doing this.

**Solution 1**

The first one goes via the garbage-collector.

```
B -> __dict__ -> C
```

this is the code:

```
>>> class B(object):
    class C(object):
        pass

>>> gc.get_referrers(B.C) # last element in the list
[<attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>, (<class '__main__.C'>, <type 'object'>), {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>, 'C': <class '__main__.C'>, '__doc__': None}] 

>>> gc.get_referrers(gc.get_referrers(B.C)[-1]) # first element in this list
[<class '__main__.B'>, [<attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>, <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>, (<class '__main__.C'>, <type 'object'>), {'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'B' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'B' objects>, 'C': <class '__main__.C'>, '__doc__': None}]]

>>> gc.get_referrers(gc.get_referrers(B.C)[-1])[0]
<class '__main__.B'>
```

Algorithm:

1. search for a class dictionairy with the same `__module__` as C
2. take the class, use the 'C' attribute
3. if this class is nested. do 1. recurively

**Solution 2**

use the source file. use inspect to get the lines of the class and scan upwards for new classes that nest it.

**Note: I know no clean way in python 2, but python 3 provides one.**